# Keyboard repeat disappeared with 22.04.1

Tags: keyboard

My system has just upgraded from 20.04 LTS to 22.04.1 LTS and the keyboard repeat function has disappeared. This is the same in all applications. The keyboard is English UK, which was the default on install. I haven't changed any settings.  I’ve looked in Settings/Keyboard but there’s no option to turn it on.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: application specific? keyboard selected? language selected? Too few details to provide any response. Please [edit] accordingly. Works fine for me in Terminal on the same OS as well as LO (all modules), What did you upgrade from?

Answer (score 1):

I looked in Settings/Accessibility, and Repeat Keys is one of the options (it was set to On). Click on the option and another dialogue box opens with sliders to set Delay and Speed. They were both set to such long intervals that I hadn't discovered that Repeat Keys was still there and turned on, even though I tried it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).